# Bitcoind with -txindex=1 still no mempool transactions

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, mastering-bitcoin

I'm reading through [Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) and trying to follow along the examples.

When I first initialized `bitcoind`, I set `txindex=1` in my `bitcoin.conf` file. In a later example I was unable to `getrawtransaction` which failed with the error *No such mempool transaction*. I re-ran `bitcoind` with the `-txindex=1` and `-reindex` flags, which took a few hours.

However I'm still unable to `getrawtransaction`, which again fails with the same error.

Have anyone experienced the same issues? Perhaps there is something else that needs to be done for this to work in `v0.16.0`?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`:

```
txindex=1
```

`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/debug.log`:

[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/103owus8psddw6t/debug.log?dl=0)

Comment: Can you give an example of a txid that fails like this?

Comment: @NateEldredge any transaction without an unspent output really, just as expected if `txindex` was set to `0`. For an example, the below transactions give me that error:

`3fd3431462b46b4adc8e3da663582993ecbfebf62ef7de4d81115b235a5020de`
`331dd436aebeb22c9b629d6a769fd3f679e18ca4c6c34b15d6b3ab9ce936cd05`
`45ea0a3f6016d2bb90ab92c34a7aac9767671a8a84b9bcce6c019e60197c134b`

Comment: Is bitcoind fully reindexed? Can you post the contents of your bitcoin.conf and debug.log files?

Comment: @AndrewChow added to the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your debug.log file, `txindex` is not enabled:

```
2018-04-22 20:40:34 LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled
```

This indicates that your bitcoin.conf is incorrect. Make sure that your bitcoin.conf file's full filename is actually bitcoin.conf (not bitcoin.conf.txt or with some other extension).

Comment: You're right, it seems as though the paths confused me a little. I specified `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` instead of `~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` which ended up saving the file as `~/Library/Application`. However I'm still a little confused as to what went down during the almost full day it spent reindexing when I ran `bitcoind -txindex=1` and subsequently `bitcoind -reindex`. I have however created the correct `bitcoin.conf` file now and will reindex and try again.

Comment: Whenever you start with `-reindex`, the blockchain will be read off disk and all of the block and chainstate databases will be rebuilt. This will happen for all `-reindex`s regardless of `-txindex`. With `-txindex`, the reindex will do the same but include more data in the databases it builds. Specifying `-reindex` will reindex even if one is not required.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for that information. It was very helpful!